# Annotations using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an essay writing test website, I input an essay using a text area and then I want to comment on that inputted text like PDF annotations/highlighted the comment I have tried the annotation API for `TinyMCE` but it throws an error

> invalid call to Attr.set. Key  data-mce-alpha :: Value  undefined :: Element
>       
>       tinymce.min.js:8:48481
>       Error: Attribute value was not simple

and `Annotation.js` is 5 years old and jquery throws an error on that
any idea how I can do it using JS and store it?

Answer (score 1):

If you used example code from here https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/annotations/ then that example code did not work for me either.

This is a part of code which was in documentation:

```
        ed.on('init', function() {
            ed.annotator.register('alpha', {
                persistent: true,
                decorate: function(uid, data) {
                    return {
                        attributes: {
                            'data-mce-alpha': data.alpha
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
        });
```

Change data.alpha to data.comment, so that piece of code should look like this:

```
ed.on('init', function() {
    ed.annotator.register('alpha', {
        persistent: true,
        decorate: function(uid, data) {
            return {
                attributes: {
                    'data-mce-alpha': data.comment
                }
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Then example will work - just need to write some text in comment prompt dialog otherwise it will throw the same error - so make sure that you will implement some kind of check if comment string is not empty.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved the issue by adding an older Jquery, 
here is the code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/annotator-full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/annotator.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var annotation{{ $questionss->id }} = $('#content{{ $questionss->id }}').annotator().annotator('addPlugin', 'Tags');;

      annotation{{ $questionss->id }}.annotator('addPlugin', 'Store', {
        prefix: '/annotation',
        loadFromSearch : {
            page : {{ $questionss->q_type_id }}
        },
        annotationData : {
            page : {{ $questionss->q_type_id }}
        },
        urls: {
            create:  '/store',
            update:  '/update/:id',
            destroy: '/delete/:id',
            search:  '/search'
        }
      });
```

hope it helps